# WCF Data Service compression for an Android client

Tags: android, wcf-data-services, odata4j

I use a WCF Data Services service that resides in a Windows Service program and get data with an Android phone using [Odata4j](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/). I get lots of data from it and I need to compress the data coming from the Data Service. I was thinking of *GZip* as a standard compressing algorythm and Android should have the necessary decoding methods.

Is it possible? I couldn't find the compression settings for my data service let alone the Android side of the decompression. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here are my findings regarding to the compression problem.

- With a WCF Data Service in a Windows Service, you *cannot create compression* because you *cannot* modify the output as there is no *HTTPContext* - it is a property of the ASP context that can be found only in IIS (Express)
- You need an IIS for compressing the data - it is easy that way
- Much to my astonishment, the compressed data could be read by odata4j *without any modification*
- It is good to know that the decompressing of the incoming data takes **notable time**, comparable to the time gained by transferring less data

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786245/how-to-decode-gzip-stream-with-odata4j-in-android) for more information.