# How to decode GZip stream with odata4j in Android

Tags: android, odata4j

I have a WCF Data Service that sends data with GZip. I intend to use [odata4j](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/) to read that compressed stream. If it is not compressed, it works fine.
What should I modify to be able to read the compressed stream via odata4j?

Here is the C# code that compresses the stream:

```
 HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
      if (httpContext != null)
        httpContext.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(httpContext.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
```

And here is the Odata4j part that reads the data:

```
 ODataConsumer consumer = ODataJerseyConsumer.create(url);
 List<OEntity> listEntities=consumer.getEntities("Data")
          .execute().toList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odata4j supports compressed content download, no additional configuration is required. However, the *uncompression task consumes so much CPU time*, that the time gained by the lesser data transfer is almost completely wasted.